# Link that will download the latest MSI installer of Google Chrome

Tags: c#, installation

Using c# to code and automatically download the latest chrome msi version.
I found https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/thank-you/?platform=WIN64_MSI&channel=stable&usagestats=0

but I think I would need to have the file in the link so that it won't open a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it directly from https://dl.google.com

E.g.: https://dl.google.com/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi

Other installer paths:

```
{
  "WIN64_MSI": "/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi",
  "WIN64_MSI_BETA": "/dl/chrome/install/beta/googlechromebetastandaloneenterprise64.msi",
  "WIN_MSI": "/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi",
  "WIN_MSI_BETA": "/dl/chrome/install/beta/googlechromebetastandaloneenterprise.msi",
  "WIN64_BUNDLE": "/dl/chrome/install/GoogleChromeEnterpriseBundle64.zip",
  "WIN_BUNDLE": "/dl/chrome/install/GoogleChromeEnterpriseBundle.zip",
  "MAC": "/dl/chrome/mac/universal/stable/gcea/googlechrome.dmg",
  "MAC_DMG_BETA": "/dl/chrome/mac/universal/beta/GoogleChromeBeta-Enterprise.dmg",
  "MAC_PKG": "/dl/chrome/mac/universal/stable/gcem/GoogleChrome.pkg",
  "MAC_PKG_BETA": "/dl/chrome/mac/universal/beta/GoogleChromeBeta-Enterprise.pkg",
  "ADMADMX": "/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip",
  "ADM": "/update2/enterprise/GoogleUpdate.adm",
  "ADMX": "/dl/update2/enterprise/googleupdateadmx.zip",
  "POLICY_DEV": "https://dl.google.com/chrome/policy/dev_policy_templates.zip",
  "POLICY_BETA": "https://dl.google.com/chrome/policy/beta_policy_templates.zip"
}
```